# Is there a simple way to change background color of row in a QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, qt4

I know you can loop through the QTableWidgetItems and change their colors but, what if I have used setCellWidget and I have cells that are not QTableWidgetItems. I can't find a simple setRowColor method. It seems like there should be since there are methods for alternating row color and whatnot. Is there a simple way to do this without sub-classing the table's delegate?

Rhetorical question:
I just want to change the row color, should I really need a whole new class for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a style sheet to your QTableWidget something like this:

```
QTableWidget::item {
    background-color: rgb(255, 85, 127);
}
```

You can set this is code as well as follows:

```
QString _CustomStyle = QString(
      "QTableWidget::item {"
      "background-color: rgba(162, 186, 60);"
      "}";
tableWidget->setStyleSheet(_CustomStyle);
```

Use your own color RGB (obviously).

Comment: Thank you. But, I'm actually looking to set an individual row's color. I believe your suggestion would color a whole table.

Comment: I did end up using CSS so I will mark this as accepted, but just know that I only needed to color a single row. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 5):

I believe with QTableWidget the easiest way setting row color would to iterate through widget items and use [setData](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtablewidgetitem.html#setData) method to specify the background color, see an example below

```
for (int column=0; column<4; column++)
{
    for (int row = 0; row<5; row++)
    {
        QTableWidgetItem *newItem = new QTableWidgetItem(tr("%1").arg((row+1)*(column+1)));
        newItem->setData(Qt::BackgroundRole, (row%2)>0 ? Qt::red : Qt::blue);
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(row, column, newItem);
    }
}
```

if you would want to make it simpler, consider using [QTableView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtableview.html) widget instead, implement your model (I guess the easiest way is to subclass [QStandardItemModel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstandarditemmodel.html)) and hold row colors there. Implement a setRowColor method or/and a slot to specify color for your data rows.

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Thanks but, what I am looking for is a way to set the background of a cell when I have used setCellWidget to put a widget in the cell. Is there a way to do this?